# gcp managed instance with terraform not working

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create regional managed instance group using terraform but facing the following error message:

1 error occurred:
    * module.gcp-lb.google_compute_backend_service.default: 1 error occurred:
    * google_compute_backend_service.default: Invalid value for group: A zone must be specified

I am not sure why resource google_compute_backend_service is asking for the zone if it is a regional managed instance group. Also zone seems to be not supported for this resource. I am following tasks:

1. create instance template with google_compute_instance_template
2. consume template in google_compute_region_instance_group_manager
3. passing the instance_group to backend in google_compute_backend_service with below syntax:
   backend = ["${var.backends}"]

I am passing the backends from the module with below synatx:

```
backends                  = {
    "0" = [
       { group = "${module.gcp-mig.instance_group}" }
    ],
  }
  backend_params    = [
    "/,http,80,10"
  ]
}
```

I am using terraform version: 0.11.13. Any kind of help/pointer is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Sorry this issue is related to http load balancer not managed instance group. Rest of code is working fine. Issue is coming in backend service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is with 2.5.0 google provider. It is working fine with google provider version 2.3.0